# How to avoid output collision in MongoDB using MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, theory

Preamble: I am familiar with JS and the concepts of NoSQL as well as the principle of MapReduce.

I was taking a closer look at MapReduce. Setting the `out`-Parameter will push the results of MR to the given collection. E.g.:

```
db.myCollection.mapReduce(myMappingFunction, myReduceFunction, {"out": "resulting_collection"})
```

Although one should not complain having such a feature I am questioning why one would use that other than trying out things in development mode.

So I can imagine - as of my personal workflow - that you try out things with MR and then again and again have a closer look at the results without the need to do the MR over and over again.

But to get to the essential question: 
**Is there any reason to use the out-Parameter in productive systems?**

Now let me explain why I am asking this:
The default case for productive systems is that such requests are explicitly or implicitly made by a specific user. Now let a hundred users at the same time do the "same" request with some specific parameters. Using `{"out": "resulting_collection"}` would then easily create collisions wouldn't it?

Comment: Map reduce should not be run according to when the user chooses but on a schedule, it is really designed for incremental aggregation jobs. However to answer your questio: what would b the problem of having one users MR$ overwrite another? Is there some kind of user data that has to be kept secret to that user?

Comment: That is what I thought and that is why I asked. So essentially you *could* say that MR in general is more for in-dev-mode than in-production-mode. Imagine a user doing a search which induces MR then and the `out`-Parameter is set to "resulting_collection". In the rare case of another user starting this process in the meantime it could give the user that first started it the results from the MR of the second one. Get it? I know that that normally does not happen, but it could theoretically couldn't it?

Comment: Nah MR is definitely for production but it is not for the same purpose as the aggregation framework which is a direct replacement for SQLs own. When would a user induce an MR based on a search? It is bad practice, not only that but your MR will get expodentially slower as the user waits and will kill your servers. To answer your question though: you output to a unique collection based upon the action and user_id you have

Comment: You misunderstood me at some points. But thanks. Basically you are saying what I thought :)

Comment: Not sure I did: when you said " Imagine a user doing a search which induces MR" it sounds to me as though you trigger MR per connection, this is a bad idea. MR is not designed for this and never was. This is where the aggregation framework comes in. Now assuming by your scenario I think your using MR to hack at relevancy searching right? In which case the FTS module built into MongoDB would be much better, or an actual FTS tech. MR would never scale here.

Comment: Yes. That is the answer I was heading to. When I was talking about non-productive mode I was talking about maintenance mode and pre-productive mode. And in productive mode, where we both agree on, we do not make use of MR user-implied but at the most event-implied. For any other I go with FTS.